# Maven 2 Assembly plugin - how to split main artifacts and dependencies into separate folders

Tags: maven-2, assemblies, maven-plugin

I am using Assembly plugin for maven to create an installation package.

For my packaging requirement, I need to split artifacts generated during the build and all dependencies into separate folders.

My current Assembly manifest is as follows:

```
<moduleSets>
  <moduleSet>
    <includes>
      <include>test:test</include>
    </includes>
    <binaries>
      <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
      <outputDirectory>lib/custom/${artifactId}</outputDirectory>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
    </binaries>
  </moduleSet>
  <moduleSet>
    <includes>
      <include>test:test</include>
    </includes>
    <binaries>
      <includeDependencies>true</includeDependencies>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>test:test</exclude>
      </excludes>
      <outputDirectory>lib/thirdParty/</outputDirectory>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
    </binaries>
  </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

First moduleset correctly generates only currently built assembly.
However, thirdParty includes the currently built assembly as well. How would I go about excluding the files already included in the first set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about using dependency:copy-dependencies? I use that to copy all deps to target/lib .

Comment: Using this with excludeTransitive and excludeScope would be a nice simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

One kludgy way to do it is with the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and an ant task. Iterate the contents of lib/custom/${artifactId} and remove any files from lib/thirdParty.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/index.html). It lets you dump all your runtime dependency jars in a directory. You might be able to hack that up to put your main jar in one folder and then dump the dependencies into another.